# What are spec files in cypress?

Tags: rspec, cypress

What is a Spec file? I have seen the spec files in cypress, angular, and in other softwares, but I have no idea what it is? Can anybody explain in layman terms ? or just explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cypress doc page on specs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Spec-files

It's a little bare but since searching brought me here first and there second, I figured I'd drop this answer here.

In short, it seems like 'spec' is synonymous with 'test file'.